# How to modify installaton sequences when you try to install some program on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installer

I have try to install some program to to drive D. But Windows installer allow to install program to C drive only! Does exist any workaround solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [Orca database editor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905) to edit Windows Installer files.
The Orca database editor is a table-editing tool available in the Windows Installer SDK and it can be used to edit your .msi files. Warning Editing an MSI file can cause serious problems that may leave your system in an unstable state.